# jquery logic to remove an alert message in rails not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

hey, hoping someone can point me at a solution....i have some javascript to remove notice messages in rails after a short interval. i've used this code previously with no problems, however, now, while the notice message is rendering just fine the remove() action is not firing. i'm using latest greatest jquery on current prod level of rails 3.

here's the javascript:

```
// display a notice message
$.notice = function(msg) {
  var notice = $('<div class="notice">')
    .html(msg)
    .appendTo('#messages');
  setTimeout(function() { notice.remove(); }, 5000);
};
```

here's the rails app.html.erb section for messages:

```
<section id="messages">
    <%= content_tag :div, flash[:notice], :class => "notice" if flash[:notice] %>
    <%= content_tag :div, flash[:alert], :class => "alert" if flash[:alert] %>
</section>
```

note that i'm not throwing any syntax errors according to firebug....any assistance greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead:

```
function notice(msg) {
  var notice = $('.notice')
    .html(msg)
    .appendTo('#messages');
  setTimeout(function() { notice.remove(); }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, i tried this out, but still not firing. getting the same behavior as with my orig code...

Comment: then im still not sure what u want to do

Comment: neal, i just want the notice element removed after the timeout setting in the js code. the initial display of the element is working fine but the removal of the element after the 5000 timeout setting is not happening...

Comment: right, and that works fine from the console. but for some reason rails isn't picking up the code out of the application.js file

Comment: idk, sorry, i dont know much abt rails

Comment: i figured it out....your input helped. think my code syntax was an issue. i simplified what i had and it ended up working...

Comment: @p2w so now pick an accepted answer that way on future questions people might want to help u more ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript and see if it works:

```
// display a notice message
$.notice = function(msg) {
  var notice = $('<div class="notice">' + msg + '</div>');
  notice.appendTo('#messages');
  setTimeout(function() { notice.remove(); }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, as with the above, i tried this out, but still getting the same behavior as with my orig code...

Comment: Is the element isn't going away in 5 seconds? Can you be a bit more specific about the thing that's not working?

Comment: right, the element **is not** being removed after the timeout value set in the js, which is the problem.